# how to remove the powered by Sailsjs from the app

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I know that the file exists here

[Linkto the file](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/http/middleware/defaults.js#L64)

But is there an effective way to remove this header ? Like in the config files or anything ?

Please see this header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →1189
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Fri, 19 Sep 2014 20:30:24 GMT
ETag →"-514643591-gzip"
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=200
Server →Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 OpenSSL/1.0.1f
Vary →Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By →Sails <sailsjs.org>
```

I want to remove this X-Powered-by

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: What ???? There are no code to be posted from my side.. This is a question to be answered from someone who know the answer. Jeez man

Comment: I just asked you to post the code that causing problems. It is impossible for us to guess the answer to a question if we can't see what is wrong. Also you can't just add a link to some code; the link could be removed in the future and people will not click random links etc.

Comment: There is no problem. But I have updated the question to have what the headers looks like.

Comment: // res.header('X-Powered-By', 'Sails <sailsjs.org>');  https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/http/middleware/defaults.js#L175

Comment: This is not effective. Where ever there is an update to sails core I have to change it every time. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your `http.js` config file just comment out the line with `poweredBy`.

See http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/http.js.html

Comment: I cannot see this line ? Where is it exactly ? Are you sure ?

Comment: poweredBy: function xPoweredBy(req, res, next) {
      res.header('X-PowBy', 'Express');
      next();
    }